# Unable to transfer file over Bluetooth using code

Tags: file, file-upload, upload

I am trying to transfer file over Bluetooth using code. I am using socket programming to transfer file. I have successfully made Bluetooth connection(Samsung Galaxy Tab) established with another device(Htc Desire).

Now problem is, i can send any text message but unable to send any file between device.

Please any body help me about this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in need of some sort of application-layer protocol for transferring files to layer on top of your working socket connection.

I'm unfamiliar with the details of these devices but you can probably use a standard protocol, such as [FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) or [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), in which case there is likely to be a built-in (OS-level) API you can use to effect the transfer.

Alternatively, you can roll your own protocol.  It could be as simple as this:

```
1) Send 64-bit int containing string length of filename (bytes)
2) Send filename string
3) Send 64-bit int containing length of file in bytes
4) Send contents of file
5) Disconnect
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Drew. I will follow your suggestion and try to implement it as soon as possible.